# AppleScript to bring browser to foreground on refresh

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript

Basically my issue is I have a web browser (Chrome) running Qminder monitor displaying a queue but I want to show other stuff on the display at the same time.

The idea is that when someone is called, Qminder refreshes the browser window to show the update.

Is there a way to write a script that can monitor 24/7 for this browser refresh and switch the browser window back to the foreground?

I will already be making a script that will switch between the digital signage and the Qminder queue on regular intervals, but figuring out this key part of having the screen show the person being called is the most important part.

Answer (score 1):

In the browser, we don't actually reload the page, we also listen to WebSocket events and add people into the UI dynamically.

You can write a script directly against the Qminder API, which will send you WebSocket events when someone is called. Alternatively, you can receive webhooks when you have a public-facing web server.

From an user experience perspective, it would be better to show the queue at all times. This shows your visitors where they are in the queue at a glance. For additional signage, we suggest you add another screen. :)

You should check out [the Qminder API doc](https://qminderapp.com/docs/api/). You'll find useful information under the Events and Webhooks section. (Note, that the Events section is geared towards using the [Qminder Javascript library](https://github.com/Qminder/javascript-api))

As for showing and hiding applications: [Hide Application](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AppleScript_Programming/Advanced_Code_List/Hide_Application). You can integrate it into a non-AppleScript solution via the [osascript(1)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html) program.